# Escape Windows-style /arg in Cygwin/MSYS

Tags: escaping, cygwin, msys

I need to execute Visual Studio's lib.exe from a MSYS environment, but arguments like "/WX /NOLOGO" are automatically replaced with "C:/dev/MinGW/msys/1.0/WX", for example.

How do I deactivate that behavior? I tried single/double quotes and even `` lib `echo /WX` ... `` but that doesn't solve it.

Comment: How about quoting the arguments? `.... "/WX/NOLOGO"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you can use `-switch` idiom instead of `/switch`, example

```
attrib +h -s
```

instead of

```
attrib +h /s
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/baby-cygwin.sh)

Comment: Unforuntately, that doesn't work for all windows tools -- some don't understand `-` instead of `/`

Answer (score 1):

Use double slashes:

```
lib //WX //NOLOGO
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MSYS2, use the `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL` enviroment variable.
To disable all parameters use `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="*"`
Read more about it in the manual. https://www.msys2.org/docs/filesystem-paths/